# Поиск одинаковых значений в массиве php

Tags: php

Необходимо найти повторяющиеся элементы в массиве для этого я пишу следующие

```
$fin = [5,1,1,2,2,3]
$temp = []; 
$result = []; 
foreach($fin as $k => $v) 
{ 
    if ( !in_array($v,$temp) ){
        $result[$k]["ID"] = $v;
        $result[$k]["COUNT"] = count($v); 
    }
} 
var_dump($result);
```

Проблема в том, что в `$result` попадает только самое последние совпадение, подскажите что делается не так?

Comment: используй [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php) и смотри где значение > 1

Comment: `$arr = [5,1,1,2,2,3];
$count_values_arr = array_count_values($arr);    

$count_values_arr_filtered = array_filter($count_values_arr, function ($elem) {
    return($elem > 1);
});

print_r($count_values_arr_filtered);`

Comment: вы забыли `foreach($fin as $k => $v)`

Comment: Алексей зачем в ответе не отписываетесь?

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался!